# How to store 100000 rows and 100000 columns values (as a result of computation) in a cell array Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am currently working on a sparse matrix 'A' of 100000 rows and 100000 columns.

I am trying to use this to calculate the shortest path between all the nodes using the `graphshortestpath` function.

I need to store the path for each and every node in an variable for later computation.

Currently for smaller set of data, I am able to achieve this using these set of commands

```
pathoutput=cell(70,70);
for i=1:70
    for j=1:70
        [dist1,path1,pred1]=graphshortestpath(A,i,j,'Method','Bellman-Ford');
        pathoutput{i,j}=path1;
        save('test.mat','pathoutput');
        disp(pathoutput);
    end
end
```

Suppose if in my results for path, for node 1 it is only the value 7 and in other it is [723 6 1 2025], how can I save this result of 100000 rows and 100000 columns?

However,Cell array does not seem to support such a huge data.

If I set `pathoutput=cell(100000,100000)`I am getting an error message.

Error using cell Maximum variable size allowed by the program is exceeded.

Could you suggest an alternative way to achieve this.

Thank you.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html

Comment: do you really need a 100000 by100000 array? this is 100 gb of memory...  the best thing will be to save to file by parts...

Comment: @Count Yeah the size of my sparse matrix is 100000 by100000. Is there any workaround to achieve this?

Comment: is it sparse? how sparse is it?

Comment: I created a sparse matrix to calculate shortest paths. I am not sure about  what is meant by how sparse matrix is.

Comment: It means: Which fraction of the values in your matrix is nonzero? Actually I would be surprised if a distance matrix would be very sparse, perhaps if you define 'no path' to be represented by 0 distance.

Comment: If you are curious how big you can make your variables, just try to initialize them and see what the limit is. For my system I can do `clear, C = cell(100000,10000);`, but it will fail if I add another zero. Hence, if it is not  sparse, I would have to store it in at least 10 parts. Besides this, if you want to store a huge block of numbers (for example: just the distance and not the entire path), usually using a matrix is recommended over a cell as it requires less space.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. My original data has 99000 rows. I tried to generate ID's so that reduced the node IDs to the range 1:42700. I tried the commands 
             clear, C = cell(42700,42700);
but got an out of memory error. I was thinking to use cell array because I need to find the paths between all pairs of nodes. I am not sure of how to save the paths by parts in cell array/file. I will be needing the path for my further computation. I am curious to know if there is an alternative way to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`matfile` function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matfile.html?searchHighlight=matfile) to read/write your data directly in a file. The 100 GB is therefore managed by your hard drive and not your RAM.

Here is some code that shows how to read, write and append cells.

```
A = {1:3, 2, 0
     0  , 5, 8};
save('A.mat', 'A','-v7.3');
clear A

matObj = matfile('A.mat','Writable',true);
matObj.A(1,2) = {[2 2]};       %modify one cell
matObj.A(3,3) = {[10 10 10]};  %append one isolated cell  => creates empty cells 
matObj.A(4,:) = {1, 1, 2};     %append a full row

disp(matObj.A)
```

This gives

```
A = 

    [1x3 double]    [2]    [0]
    [         0]    [5]    [8]

matObj.A = 

    [1x3 double]    [1x2 double]    [         0]
    [         0]    [         5]    [         8]
              []              []    [1x3 double]
    [         1]    [         1]    [         2]
```

---

Reading is performed this way

```
%read
matObj = matfile('A.mat');
loadedData = matObj.A(1,1);
```

It gives

> loadedData =
>
> ```
> [1x3 double]
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try to workout using MAT file. I need the results to use for later computations. Is there a way to read from MAtfile,to perform some calculations?

Comment: Please see the edit on how to read some data. The `matObj` is just like a regular matlab variable, but stored in ROM instead of RAM.

Comment: Got it.This should be helpful for my data. One small doubt, I tried using the commands to write the data to matfile 

   
     matObj = matfile('A1.mat','Writable',true);
     matObj.A1(42691,42631) = {[2 2]};
   

I got the error message that 'Matrix API is called with negative size or index. '